# Materlialize CSS - Select Componenent - Setting default value with Javascript

Tags: javascript, materialize

I have a tough time with Materialize CSS and Select compoment.

Code goes like this:

```
<select id="selectCompId">
      <option value="1">Option 1</option>
      <option value="2">Option 2</option>
      <option value="3">Option 3</option>
</select>
```

When i visit the form i always get either value 1, 2 or 3 based on some DB query. Now, if i get 2 i want to set selected on option number 2 as initial selection. I'm having issues doing so.

Tried doing this:
document.getElementById('selectCompId').value = '2' but it seems like it doesn't work with this materialize component or i'm doing it wrong.

Whole code can be found here:
https://jsfiddle.net/536Lu1xe/1/

Expected result:
Initial value set to desired value (let's say 2 in this case).

Solution -> https://jsfiddle.net/536Lu1xe/2/
At the bottom, under script tags:

```
var elem = document.querySelector('#selectCompId');
var instances = M.FormSelect.init(elem);
document.querySelector('#selectCompId option[value="2"]').setAttribute('selected', 'selected');
M.FormSelect.init(elem);
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to programmatically select an option in a select box.

In order to do that, we have to select all the options in a select box and select the desired option. The challenge here is to define the option that needs to be selected. In this case, I'm using the index for this.

Let's see how that looks like in code.

```js
let n = 1; // the index of the option that needs to be selected. In this case, we want to select Item 2 (the option at index=1)

// the following line will select the <select/> on the page
const select = document.querySelector('select');

// now we have to loop through all options and select the one at Index=1 
select.querySelectorAll('option')[n].selected = true;
```

```html
<select>
  <option value="1">Item 1</option>
  <option value="2">Item 2</option>
  <option value="3">Item 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thx, i used parts of your solution and parts of other to get what i need :) I also posted link and full solution to my first post for future references, if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `selected` attribute to select:

```
<select>
  <option value="1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="2" selected>Option 2</option>
  <option value="3">Option 3</option>
</select>
```

EDIT: 
You'll also need to re-initialize Select after updating the value:

```
const elem = document.getElementById('select_id');
M.FormSelect.init(elem);
```

Comment: How can i add this dynamically based on value i'm getting? For example one time i'm getting "2", next time "3" etc...

Comment: Ah, well materialize doesn't use `select` tag for its `Select` component. It is using `input` with a `data-target` attribute which you'll need to modify.

Comment: Care to elaborate a bit better? Or maybe add to my fiddler example?

Comment: Sorry my bad, it does use select. You might need to re-initialize your select after setting the value:  const elem = document.getElementById('select_id');
   M.FormSelect.init(elem);

Comment: I managed to solve it. You were correct with re-initializing component again after setting what needed. How i did it:
https://jsfiddle.net/536Lu1xe/2/